# es6 not allow to extent an 'import' object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here is test file 'Test.js'

```
export const a=1
```

Here is import file

```
import * as Test from './Test.js'
Test.b=2
```

Then create-react-app occurs error:

> "export 'b' (imported as 'Test') was not found in './Test'

But it gets right if I use 'require' instead of 'import':

```
var Test = require('./Test.js')
Test.b=2
console.log(Test.b)
```

It really makes me confused, I will be appreciated if anyone can give me a help

Comment: What exactly is the question? Why ES6 was designed to work that way? Even if we could tell you, what does it actually change? You already know how to deal with the situation.

Comment: I'm a little confused... you're importing a module and trying to access a property `b`, but you only export `a`?

Answer (score 1):

ES modules are read-only, `*` import can't be modified in native implementations and should never be modified for anything but testing purposes.

The writability of modules can differ between implementations. `create-react-app` uses Webpack which doesn't physically protect module object, so it's possible to modify it when it's imported with `require`, although you shouldn't do that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it's not relate to react, but I just want to extend another existing module, I know it's a very basic question, but no kidding it's my first time confront this problem, except "require", is there any ES6 style expression can achieve the purpose?

Comment: require isn't ES6. It's CommonJS module that works only because Webpack supports it. If you need to extend existing module, provide a wrapper module that extends it, `export * from './Test.js'; export const b ...`'. And import it instead of original one. That's how it's usually done.